# unable to read macaroon path (check the network setting!): admin.macaroon: no such file or directory on lncli getinfo

Tags: lightning-network, lightning-network-daemon

Just started lnd for the first time connected to a bitcoind node. Do `lncli getinfo` and this is the error message. How can I get past this?

EDIT: Would like to add that I'm using lnd on testnet, however lncli is looking in the mainnet folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the issue, lncli needed to be set to testnet and you need to create a wallet as well

```
lncli --network=testnet create
lncli --network=testnet getinfo
```

Comment: The answer should be more general. try mentioning the fact that one needs to provide a proper --rpcserver and --macaroonpath to match both `lnd` and `lncli`. For example: if lnd was started with:
`lnd --rpclisten=localhost:10003 --listen=localhost:10031 --restlisten=localhost:8003 --datadir=data `
then lncli should be started with:
`lncli --rpcserver=localhost:10003 --macaroonpath=data/chain/bitcoin/testnet/admin.macaroon`

supposing `lnd` was to be used with the `testnet` flag. The flags `network=testnet` or `-n testnet` are just a particular scenario of this.

Answer (score 1):

After installation of the lnd for the first time you should initialize a wallet with a command: `lncli create`

Here is description of startup commands:

```
lncli help
...
Startup:
create          Initialize a wallet when starting lnd for the first time.
unlock          Unlock an encrypted wallet at startup.
changepassword  Change an encrypted wallet's password at startup.
```

It may require you to create the path:

```
mkdir -p <path from error message>
```